# After submitting form redirect back to previous page in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

I have a controller which is routed through `Route::controller()`.

I have a `getEdit` and a `postEdit` function. I'm linking to the `getEdit`-function from different locations and want the user to be redirected TO that location after making changes within the form and submitting it.

I used the `Redirect::back()` method after successfully saving to the database but unfortunately I don't get redirected to the requested page BEFORE `getEdit` but instead get back to `getEdit`.

Do I have the possibility to change that behavior?

Comment: How about passing the url before edit to the controller as param?

Comment: Thought of that, too. But it would have to be a query string (like `/edit/11?back=route/to/action`) for it to work, am I right?

Comment: Edited. If its still not it, I don't know...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After searching and trying I came up with a solution which seems to be perfect for my scenario and seems also pretty clean to me.

Instead of using URL parameters or any of that kind I simply set the Session key `url.intended` to `URL::previous()` in my `getEdit` function.

```
Session::put('url.intended', URL::previous());  // using the Facade
session()->put('url.intended', URL::previous(); // using the L5 helper
```

Within my `postEdit` function I simply do a `return Redirect::intended('/')`.

Works like a charm and solves my issue completely.

Comment: Typo(replace t with d) had me for a minute should be `Session::put('url.intended', URL::previous()); `

Comment: What if there is any validation error in the form? User will be redirected to the same page and the same page is stored in the session. Also tried to edit the answer to add the missing closing bracket but apparently the edit must be at least 6 characters!

Comment: I guess to my last point this can be done: ```$hasErrors = Session()->has('errors');

        if ($hasErrors === false) {
            session()->put('url.intended', URL::previous());
        }```

Comment: Validation of course is handled before the intended url will be put into session.

Answer (score 1):

To add an example using Laravel 5 to Tim's answer:

In your controller methods that have an edit form:

```
Session::put('requestReferrer', URL::previous());
```

This will store the URL of the previous page that linked to the edit form as a session var `requestReferrer`.

To have your update method redirect back to this variable:

```
return redirect(Session::get('requestReferrer'));
```

I'm assuming if more than one form is open at once by the user that this may not give the expected behavior.  If someone suggests a better revision I will edit this post to include it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't see the relevance in addition to my answer? In your solution (that also isn't L5-specific) you also can't use the intented redirect. What if the session isn't present? You'll get an error.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't realize url.intended was reserved for the intended() method.  My intent was to add clarification as to what the example you gave was doing, which by attempting to do so exposed what your example is actually doing!  I see intended has a fallback mechanism.  I'll delete this answer in a bit.  A session must be active for either to work yes?

Comment: I see now my initial implementation blunder, I missed the typo in the Facade use for 'intended' >.<

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this via a middleware:

```
<?php

namespace Kjjdion\Larapack\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IntendUrl
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // set intended url for redirect
        $request->session()->put('url.intended', $request->url());

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then simply call the middleware in your controller `construct` for the methods you want to store for redirection.